# configure claims authentication in Sharepoint Which has configurd in 2 different servers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying to implement claims based authentication in SharePoint which is configured in 2 different servers, previously it was in one server and it worked fine with a **custom STS(.net mvc application)** provider.

Now I have followed same steps to configure **custom STS(.net mvc application)** on SharePoint Server 1, but the token is not accepting by SharePoint its again redirecting to custom STS provider.

sharepoint.com -> redirecting to CustomSts.com (authentication done) posting token to sharepoint.com but sharepoint.com is again redirecting to CustomSts.com (as already authenticated ) its redirecting to sharepoint.com. cycle repeats, that should not be happen

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed by maintaining same time in 2 sharepoint servers and CustomSTS server.

Actually one of the sharepoint server time is different from customSTS server time so, sharepoint application is treating that incoming claims are expired after login, so its again redirecting to CustomSTS server for live claims. We maintained the same time between the servers, this fixes our issue.

Thanks friends for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The token  seems to be expiring . Set the customConfiguration.DefaultTokenLifetime = new System.TimeSpan(8, 0, 0); Refer the link : http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/12/sliding-sessions-with-sharepoint-2010-and-claims/. Also Refer the steps taken in this post : [SharePoint 2013 ADFS login local token cache always expired](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79864/sharepoint-2013-adfs-login-local-token-cache-always-expired/81310#81310)

Comment: am using Asp.net for CUstomSTS provider