# MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '10' seconds. Contact your administrator for details

Tags: 2010, authentication, adfs

I have sharepoint application using the ADFS authentication provider .
Intermittently i am receiving the below error when trying to login to my application.

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '10' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.

Also , i end up getting continuous loop from ADFS to Sharepoint and vice versa .

Could anyone provide help on this .

UPDATE : I faced issue someday back , but none of options are working

[SharePoint 2013 ADFS login local token cache always expired](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79864/sharepoint-2013-adfs-login-local-token-cache-always-expired/81310#81310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is more related to  lifetime of tokens (when SharePoints LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow is longer than the SAML token lifetime from ADFS). Try the below fix and see if it fix the issue.

Highly recommended try this in your test farm 1st.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/08/09/setting-the-login-token-expiration-correctly-for-sharepoint-2010-saml-claims-users.aspx

http://iamprogrammerdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/same-client-browser-session-has-made-6.html